# Can anyone see why I'm getting an "invalid hook" error? I have tried and tried and can't see what the problem is

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React but earlier I changed something and no matter how i strip my code to the bare basics of a hook I cant seem to escape this error..

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Here is my React function component...]

```
import { useState } from "react";

export function GetPokemonInfo() {
    const [pokemonState, setPokemonState] = useState();

    let number = 1;

    setPokemonState(number * 2);
    console.log(pokemonState);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hi</p>;
        </div>
    );
}
GetPokemonInfo();
```

I should add that i spun up the app with create-react-app and have  no other components rendering other than the main app and this one component.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do with your hook? If you are trying to call this hook at the beginning of the page rendering, you could wrap it with ```useEffect``` with empty dependency array. Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-flower-jj7l8i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much for replying and for going to the trouble of making a working version. It was just to start using state, and i couldn't figure out why I keep getting that error message. I will try your example. Because I am new here I am not at a level where im allowed to upvote your solution, but thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes up due to a wrong component implementation (the implementation of a component is by using the component as JSX tag like `<GetPokemonInfo />`) and You call `GetPokemonInfo()`  where GetPokemonInfo is a functional component that has an `useState` hooks in it. When you remove it, the error will go, but you still have another problem.

If you want to init the `pokemonState`, just wrap the setState inside a useEffect with no dependency.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const number = 1;
    setPokemonState(number * 2);
  }, []);
```

If you want to watch the state change , just use useEffect block to wrap your console.log. The console.log will be called on any pokemonState changes only not on every render.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(pokemonState);
  }, [pokemonState]);
```

And your GetPokemonInfo component will become:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function GetPokemonInfo() {
  const [pokemonState, setPokemonState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const number = 1;
    setPokemonState(number * 2);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(pokemonState);
  }, [pokemonState]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hi</p>;
    </div>
  );
}
```

and import it inside the parent component:

```js
import GetPokemonInfo from './GetPokemonInfo'

...

function YourParentComponent() {

   ...

   return (
       ...
       <GetPokemonInfo />
       ...
   )
}
```